# Build project with multiple Git repos

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote

A bit of a theoric question here about git workflows:

I am building a boilerplate I wanna use to make quick websites and webapps. That project lives in its own repo (https://github.com/simonwalsh/startapp).

Since I'm building alot of wordpress sites, I'm simultaneously building a boilerplate theme compatible with the aforementioned front-end project. That project also lives in a repo (https://github.com/simonwalsh/startpress).

**1. What would be the best way to create a new project from those two boilerplates?**

I was thinking of forking StartPress and then forking StartApp into the StartPress fork, but that means I will have two repos in the same project and I don't know if that is a good practice or anything...

**2. Also, if I wanna use `git remotes` to keep the forks in sync with the original repos, would that work?**

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using Git submodules, their basically repos within repos.

Here's a link to an introduction: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thanks! Are started checking it out and it seems to be what i need albeit a bit complicated! :)